# Replace OpenSSL by polarSSL

Tags: polarssl

I have a server which uses OpenSSL for its basic TLS/SSL services. I wanted to replace OpenSSL with PolarSSL in my server if possible. So I wanted to know if we have programs with PolarSSL support for these services (preferably my current programs) :

```
WebServer with SSL support (currently I use Apache)

SSH Client/Server (currently I use OpenSSH)

IPSec (currently I use IPSec-Tools)
```

if there isn't something like that , how can i replace OpenSSL by polarSSL in them ?

Comment: StackOverflow is about practical programming questions. You should consider asking on https://serverfault.com/ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webserver: I used to use Apache but am now a happy [Hiawatha webserver](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/) user. [Hiawatha switched to PolarSSL](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/weblog/32) a while ago.

> Another big change is that OpenSSL has been replaced with PolarSSL.
>   Unlike OpenSSL, PolarSSL is well documented and easy to learn.
>   Hiawatha's SSL library is much cleaner and simpler due to PolarSSL. No
>   more dirty callback stuff to make it work.